# How to config USB bandwidth allocation using Powershell?

Tags: windows-8, usb, ffmpeg, powershell, bandwidth

Actually I read [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538112) but don't know how to use it in Powershell.

It looks like

> MaximumTransferSize member of the USBD_PIPE_INFORMATION

is obsolete. Do you have any solution to limit USB bandwidth allocation?

In case you guys want to know why I need this. It's because I want to streaming 3 webcam at the same time from my little laptop :)

> Q: What happens currently if you connect all three webcams?
>
> A: I coudn't the run ffmpeg to stream the third camera. FFmpeg shows the error mention that bandwidth is not enough. I figure this out how to do it in [ubuntu](http://renoirsrants.blogspot.com.es/2011/07/multiple-webcams-on-zoneminder.html) by limit each camera bandwidth allocation. Anyway Thank you for your response.

PS. I'm using Windows 8.

Best Regards

Comment: What Windows version are you using? The first link clearly states: `In Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, and later versions, MaximumTransferSize member of the USBD_PIPE_INFORMATION structure is obsolete. The USB driver stack ignores the value in MaximumTransferSize for both composite and non-composite devices.`

Comment: @Seth I'm using windows 8 but would you mind prepare both Windows XP  and Windows 8 solutions?

Comment: @SarinSuriyakoon Read Seth's comment again. `MaximumTransferSize` is oblolete - that means it's not used so there is no point in setting it.

Comment: What happens currently if you connect all three webcams? What you're looking at is more meant to be used on an application or even driver level. Doing this in PowerShell could be quire complicated as you'd essentially write C# Code invoking Win32 code from what I can tell.

Comment: I coudn't the run ffmpeg to stream the third camera. FFmpeg shows the error mention that bandwidth is not enough. I figure this out how to do it in [ubuntu](http://renoirsrants.blogspot.com.es/2011/07/multiple-webcams-on-zoneminder.html) by limit each camera bandwidth allocation. Anyway Thank you for your response.